# How to stop background(upload image into server) service in android?

Tags: android, image, web-services, background-process, background-service

Suppose i run a web service in background(*upload 100 images in binary format*),If i want to stop then upload stop.If i want again start upload images then again start upload and also stop service (stop upload image into server) if i want. It is possible. If it is possible. Please explain how it is possible.

In this situation, i use AsyncTask Class but when call `onPostExecute()` then not call `onCancelled()` during executing `onPostExecute()`. So How it is possible.

that means i talk about above, i sent request into server for upload 100 images. So when start upload images then images upload running but once i stop (stop upload image)service then stop upload image into server.

If i again start service then again start service.

Please help me anybody via example or tutorial or helpful resource links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First create Service .
- Run one thread in that service .
- In Run method use while loop.
- Maintain one Boolean variable to stop and stat loop.

  ```
   while(your boolean variable){
      //your upload tax.
   }
  ```

I think this will help you.

Comment: please give me a simple example which can guide line for stackoverflow users.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clarify the question a bit, you want to stop the AsyncTask or the background service ?

What triggers the "stop" and where ?

In general I suggest you check if you were cancelled between each image upload but that won't stop the upload mid-file.
This requires some more knowledge on how you are performing the upload.

Also, It sounds like you should consider a networking library like OkHTTP / Retrofit / Volley

Comment: how to running service stop. please explain me. please

Comment: You can call stopService() or stopSelf()  but you should stop the upload gracefully first

Comment: in stopService(), need stop image upload service any way.